# Submitting requests to a job running in a Dataproc cluster in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataproc

I have a Dataproc cluster running in GCP. The cluster has a spark job which is always running and listening for requests.
Upon receiving the requests, it needs to process it and returns the result in a json.

The requests to the cluster will always be coming from my organisation's on-prem machines.

How can I have this setup? can I get some guidance please.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Is the request  an incoming file event? If yes then you can Cloud Pub/Sub which has a filtering-by-attribute API. You can set up a Cloud Function to subscribe from your Cloud Pub/Sub topic. The function can then start up a DataProc cluster using the DataProc client library, or do any other action.
[https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification#options][1]
2. Ensure that your on-premises machines and the Dataproc cluster are in the same network


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification#options